# How to POST a list of files in R

Tags: r, httr

Currently using `httr` package

```
Files <- c("mypath.png", “test.png”)

R  <- POST(url, body = list(x = upload_file(#FIles),b = “test” ))
```

Trying to post multiple files with same key

Similar to the script below from python

```
files = [('file', open('report.xls', 'rb')), ('file', open('report2.xls', 'rb'))]
```

Comment: You're not providing enough information to anyone to even make a suggestion.  What happens? What messages do you get? How could anyone else try out some code that would work? Have you tried the examples and vignettes provided by the package?

Comment: #Add Arguments
params[["file_in_bytes"]] <- list( upload_file("test.jpg","image/jpeg") , upload_file("debug.PNG","image/png"))
#API Address
API_ENDPOINT <- paste(API_ENDPOINT ,"smtpCloudFileHtmlAttachmentInlineImage",sep="")
r <- POST(API_ENDPOINT , body = params, encode = "multipart", verbose())
cat(str(content(r, "text")), "\n") # text content

Error in curl::handle_setform(handle, .list = req$fields) : Unsupported value type for form field 'file_in_bytes'.

Comment: Please edit your question with all pertinent information available.

Answer (score 0):

## Need to be done in curl

**#Workaround in curl library.**
params=list()
for (file in embImgList)
{params <- append(params, list(FILES= form_file(path = file)))}

Comment: Please use formatting tools to format your answer. This is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked

```
httr::POST(url = upload_url,
                    add_headers(`Authorization` = authorization),
                    body = list(files = upload_file(file_location[1]),
                                files = upload_file(file_location[2]),
                                files = upload_file(file_location[3]),
                                files = upload_file(file_location[4]),
                                files = upload_file(file_location[5])),
                    encode = "multipart",
                    verbose()
                )
```